# How can I optimize the are of a rectangle inscribed between a line and the x axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

[image]

I have these two images. For the first one, I have a parabola and the rectangle inside it. It says that the function on the right is the area function of the rectangle.

I understand how to do the first optimization problem. I have

The point where the square touches the parabola is (x,y). 
The area is 2xy

If i consider only the positive x values

Then the width is y or $y=9-x^2$

So substituting it into the area function we have

$A = 2x(9-x^2) = 18x-2x^3$

Now to optimize, I would take the derivative of the area:

$18-6x^2$

$x=\pm \sqrt{3}$

Then I plug back in my positive x value to get $y = 6$

This the $A = 2(\sqrt{3})6 = 12\sqrt{3}$ and the length is $2\sqrt{3}$ and the width is 6. Is this correct?

For the second problem, I don't know how to approach it.

The line is $y = 6-2x$

Then similarly the point where the rectangle touches the line is $(x,y)$

The area is just $xy$ this time

$y= 6-2x$ and so the area is $x(6-2x) = 6x-2x^2$

Then to optimize I would take the derivative and get

$6-4x$ so $x = 1.5$

Then $y = 6-2(1.5) = 3 $

So the area = $3(1.5) = 4.5$

Is this correct? I'm confused because the graphs shown in the question show those same dimensions so I'm not sure if I'm finding the largest dimensions of the rectange?

Comment: What is necessary in the statement of the second problem for it to have a solution?

Comment: That it already does.  Why is the area xy?